# Do while loop - powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a question about the following loop that im trying to run on powershell

```
if($activity.id.count -eq 1) {
    $activity2 = $activity.countID
}

elseif($activity.id.count -eq 0) {

   write-host "ALERT . Activity did not start  yet"

$number = 20
$i = $activity

   do {
       write-host " $i"
         if ($i.id.count -eq 1) { write-host 'go to next step'; break;
       }
       else
           {
              {
              write-host 'Waiting for' $i
              }
           }

         Start-Sleep 10
        }
        while ($i -le $number)

      Wait-Job $activity
}
```

It waits until activity has an Id, which correspond to activityID set count= 1. If it does not have an Id, count = 0 ; meaning  activity did not start yet.
My loops keeps running  - getting the following message : ' Waiting for' but it does not exit when the count =1 (the activity started)

What am i missing ?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you aren't updating your `$i` variables so it never changes and therefore the loop is never broken/ended

Comment: How can i achieve the solution ?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `$activity`? You will need to do update it inside the do..while loop, I don't think you need to use `$i` at all

Comment: @user9191 Please update your question with more information as we don't have enough information to effectively help you.

Comment: Activity is calling  the cloud and returning a set of information . One of the them is the activityID .Its a lot of code lines - The code is working  when theres an accId , but if the activity did not start - i want this loop to wait and if the count =1, move on